How to divide a canvas into my squares number
I have a 5504 x 1504 canvas , I looking for algorithm to find how many squares can spawn in canvas , the number of spawn square is different , for example for total 200 spawn , the algorithm should be calculate what is the size of square for 200 spawn and of course if the spawn number change to 500 then the size of squares should be different as well.
I hope I can explain what I need , thanks.

5504 * 1504 is 8278016. This divided by 200 is a little more than 41390. Square root of this is a little more than 203.... so draw 200 squares of 203x203 pixels leaving just 36216 pixels uncovered by a square. PS: no guarantees this division will make it possible to apply to your canvas without overlap though

thanks for reply , so at this time the algorithm should be work to find the reduce size of the spawn objects , for example if 203x203 is not good then algorithm should change it to 200 x 200

@Mehdi well then .. implement it that way ^^ I think the first comment basically tells you exactly what steps are rewuired

@pmg: That method would say you could put 200 squares of 203×203 pixels in a rectangle that is 8,278,016×1, but the number that would fit is 0.

@Eric: "PS: no guarantees this division will make it possible to apply to your canvas without overlap though"

@pmg: So it is useless as a method and not helpful or worth entering as a comment.

Basically what you are trying to achieve in other words is

You have given

dimensions (width * height)
amount of squares (squaresAmount)
squares are arranged in a grid (and without rotation)


You look for

squareSize


So that

squareAmount squares of size squareSize are guaranteed to fit into width * height
squareSize is big as possible



So what you could do is something like e.g.
public float CalculateSquareSize(int width, int height, int squareAmount)
{
    var maxSquareSize = 0f;

    // Try to fit the squares by trying different numbers of columns and rows
    // we basically try every possible grid dimensions and fit them to the given width and height
    for (var columns = 1; columns <= squareAmount; columns++)
    {
        // Calculate the number of rows required to fit the squares
        // we use ceil here as one row might be incomplete 
        var rows = Mathf.CeilToInt((float)squareAmount / columns);

        // Ensure that the resulting grid still fits within the given dimensions
        if (columns <= width && rows <= height)
        {
            // Calculate the potential square size for this configuration
            var squareSizeForThisConfig = Mathf.Min(width / (float)columns, height / (float)rows);

            // Maximize the square size
            if (squareSizeForThisConfig > maxSquareSize)
            {
                maxSquareSize = squareSizeForThisConfig;
            }
        }
    }

    // Until here we only tried column wise layout with a potential incomplete row
    // but maybe a row wise layout with potentially incomplete column can fit bigger squareSize
    for (int rows = 1; rows <= squareAmount; rows++)
    {
        var columns = Mathf.CeilToInt((float)squareAmount / rows);

        if (columns <= width && rows <= height)
        {
            var squareSizeForThisConfig = Mathf.Min(width / (float)columns, height / (float)rows);

            if (squareSizeForThisConfig > maxSquareSize)
            {
                maxSquareSize = squareSizeForThisConfig;
            }
        }
    }

    return maxSquareSize;
}

If you want to additionally round this to a more "beautiful" square size you can of course still do so even though it would mean to give away a bit of the screen space
